# Mysql запрос для интернет магазина с использованием checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, checkbox

Как бы вы подошли к решению такой задачи?

На сайте есть фильтр для подбора по характеристикам.
- бренд, цвет, стиль и .т.п.

Характеристики для фильтрации отмечаются чекбоксами и затем Ajax передает на сервер перечень отмеченных и неотмеченных чекбоксов.
Страница (`php`) на сервере, на основании ОТМЕЧЕННЫХ чекбоксов формирует запрос к БД (`MySql`) и получает количество (count) товаров, которые имеют отмеченные в чекбоксах характеристики. Результат возвращается в браузер и выводится окошко: найдено X товаров.
Собственно как в Яндекс Маркете.

Я написал код

Checkbox(ы) (только пример. на самом деле групп с чекбоксами будет больше)

```xml
<div id="checkboxes">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Zara" >zara</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Nike" >nike</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Adidas" >Adidas</label>
</div>

<div id="color">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="red" >red</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="black" >black</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="blue" >blue</label> 
</div>

<div id="style">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="classic" >classic</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="modern" >modern</label>              
</div>
```

Mysql запрос

```sql
$brand = $_POST['brand'];
$color = $_POST['color'];
$style = $_POST['style'];


$Query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE brand IN ('" . implode("','", $brand) . "') AND color IN ('" . implode("','", $color) . "') AND style IN ('" . implode("','", $style) . "')";
$QueryResult = mysqli_query($connection , $Query);


while($QueryRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QueryResult)){
    ?>
    <div><p><?php echo $QueryRow['cost'];?></p></div>
    <div><img src="<?php echo $QueryRow['img']; ?>"></div>
    <?php
    }
    }
        ?>
```

Проблема в следующем. если выбираю хотя бы по одному параметру в каждой группе то всё работает, но если хотя бы одна группа будет без отмеченого чекбокса то выдаёт ошибку....Думал над использованием If но тогда нужно будет рассмотреть все возможные варианты отмеченных и не отмеченных чекбоксов,а это очень много..

так же попробовал впихнуть IF напрямую в `sql` запрос

```
$Query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE brand IN ('" . implode("','", $brand) . "') ".  if(!empty($color)){AND color IN ('" . implode("','", $color) . "')} if(!empty($style)){AND style IN ('" . implode("','", $style) . "')} ." ";
```

но тоже не работает

Может кто-нибудь помочь с решением этой проблемы?

Comment: Заведите массив с именами чекбоксов. бежите по массиву, проверяете установлен ли соотв. чекбокс, если да - то делаете `$sql.= " and имя_поля_соотв_чекбоксу in(?,?,?) " и параметры к запросу привязываете. Имя поля конечно так же из массива берете, не кодить же руками блоки для каждого случая

Comment: массив с именами чекбоксов - тоесть получается массив в массиве,так?

Comment: массив чего вы хотите в него положить. я предпалагал тупо brand=>brand, color=>color, ... правда если имена полей в БД и чекбоксов совпадают - то сопоставлять там даже нечего

Answer (score 1):

Есть один типовой ход в случаях подобных вам. Для того, чтобы не перебирать все возможные варианты, делают более простым способом.

При составлении SQL-запроса пишут основную часть и дописывают к ней WHERE 1 = 1
Остальные запросы дописывают при помощи операторов IF.

Что-то вроде:

```
$strSql = "SELECT id, name FROM table WHERE 1 = 1 ";

if(выбран фильтр по выпадающему списку городов)
   $strSql .= " and city = " .  переменная с городом ;

if(выбран фильтр по дате начала)
   $strSql .= " and date_begin => " .  переменная с датой начала ;
```

И так далее.

Ваш конкретный вариант оставляю на подумать вам самому.

Если что-то непонятно -- посмотрите, например, этот вопрос: [Задать условие вывода оператора AND](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608849/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-and)

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавь к каждому массиву в формируемом тексте запроса какой-нибудь фэйк:

```
"... WHERE brand IN ('" . implode("','", array_merge($brand, array("fake_value")) . "') AND ..."
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы сразу поймёте в чём ошибка, если посмотрите на запрос, который вы отправляете в базу данных (это полезный приём при отладке, возьмите на заметку).

Всё дело в том, что данные введённые пользователем это не данные вашей модели. В пользовательских данных может быть всё, что захочет пользователь (ваш случай, когда там пусто, ещё не самый сложный). Поэтому вам надо преобразовать пользовательские данные в данные, которые имеют смысл в вашем приложении.

```
<?php

// приведём всё к массивам (это важно, потому что с точки зрения приложения фильтры -- это списки)
$brands = (array) ($_POST['brand']?? []);
$colors = (array) ($_POST['color']?? []);
$styles = (array) ($_POST['style']?? []);


$where = [];

if (!empty($brands)) {
    $quotedBrands = array_map(function($item) use($connection) {
        // экранируем значения фильтров (это очень важно, так как пользовательские данные могут содержать небезопасные значения)
        return "'" . mysqli_escape_string($connection, (string) $item) . "'";
    }, $brands);
    $where[] = 'brand in (' . implode(', ', $quotedBrands) . ')';
}

// так же делаем для остальных фильтров

//  теперь собираем запрос
$query = 'select * from items';
if (!empty($where)) {
    $query .= ' where ' . implode(' and ', $where);
}

echo $query;
```