# Задать условие вывода оператора AND

Tags: php, sql

Как в такой ситуации правильно сформировать условия, чтобы AND выводился тогда, когда ему положено? Отправляется форма из нескольких полей, причем количество полей может быть заполнено любое.
В данном примере если значение не пустое, оно сразу подставляется с AND после WHERE, что вызывает ошибку:

```php
$q = "SELECT * FROM (  
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) as row FROM dbo.KUR_Person WHERE ";
if (!empty($raion)) {
  $q. = " CONTAINS (ADR_RAION,'\"$raion*\"')";
}
if (!empty($gorod)) {
  $q. = " AND CONTAINS (ADR_GOROD,'\"$gorod*\"')";
}
if (!empty($gorod)) {
  $q. = " AND CONTAINS (ADR_GOROD,'\"$gorod*\"')";
}
if (!empty($naspunkt)) {
  $q. = " AND CONTAINS (ADR_NASPUNKT,'\"$naspunkt*\"')";
}
if (!empty($ulica)) {
  $q. = " AND CONTAINS (ADR_ULICA,'\"$ulica*\"')";
}
if (!empty($dom)) {
  $q. = " AND ADR_DOM = '$dom'";
}
if (!empty($korpus)) {
  $q. = " AND ADR_KORPUS = '$korpus')";
}
if (!empty($kvartira)) {
  $q. = " AND ADR_KVARTIRA = '$kvartira'";
}
$q. = ") a WHERE row >= $start and row <= $end ";
```

Как заставить вставать AND там, где ему положено, чтобы он шел только в тому случае, если есть предыдущая переменная?

Comment: Чаще всего пишут `where 1=1` после него спокойно добавляются любые AND

Comment: Проще всего добавить после `WHERE` условие типа `1 = 1`.

Comment: интересно, не знал про `1=1`, спасибо. А если вместо `and` несколько `or`?

Answer (score 3):

Про `1 = 1` уже сказали. Еще вариант - сформировать массив условий, а потом склеить его при помощи `implode(' AND ', ...)`

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM (  
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) as row FROM dbo.KUR_Person";
$params = array();
if (!empty($raion)) {
  $params[] = "CONTAINS (ADR_RAION,'\"$raion*\"')";
}
if (!empty($gorod)) {
  $params[] = " CONTAINS (ADR_GOROD,'\"$gorod*\"')";
}
.......
if (count($params) > 0)
  $q .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $params)
```

> А если вместо and несколько or

Либо так же, через промежуточный массив, либо добавив условие

```
WHERE 1 = 0
```